# Dropping some textures when exporting fbx

Tags: texture-baking

I am losing some textures when exporting an FBX.  I am a total newb here so be gentle.  When I reimport the file to check it, some of the textures linked in the node have just turned to purple, while others seem to export and import fine.  The ones I struggle with are ones where I adjusted the UV map a little.  Ones with no adjustment seem to export just fine.

all nodes are connected to principle bdsf with nothing in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you're exporting for unreal engine you have to pack every external data (textures objects from other projects etc) into the .blend you're exporting. You do it by going into File>External Data>check the box on Automaticly pack into .Blend file and then save your project and export it again. I hope it did help :P